# How to format timevalue to HH:MM:SS in datalabel

Tags: graph, crystal-reports

So i have a bar graph in crystal reports. On this graph i have a data label attached to each of the graphs that displays the value of the graph in seconds, which appears like so:
[image]
 What i would like to do is format this data-label into a time formatting. So for each bar in the graph it would have the data-label appear in the following format:

HH:MM:SS.

i am able to get the time formatting to appear using the following formula:

```
local NumberVar Sec;
local NumberVar ss;
local NumberVar mm;
local NumberVar hh;
local StringVar SSS;
local StringVar MMM;

Sec := Sum ({GetAlarmSummaryDataSet2Response/GetAlarmSummaryDataSet2Result/Items/AlarmSummaryItem2.StopTime}, {GetAlarmSummaryDataSet2Response/GetAlarmSummaryDataSet2Result/Items/AlarmSummaryItem2.Section}) ;
hh := Int (Sec/3600);
mm :=Int ((Sec/60)- (60* Int(Sec/3600 )));
If mm<10 then MMM := "0" & ToText (mm,0);
If mm>9 Then MMM := ToText(mm,0) ;

ss :=Sec-(3600 * hh ) - (60 * mm ) ;
If ss<10 then SSS := "0" & ToText (ss,0);
If ss>9 Then SSS := ToText(ss,0) ;

ToText ( hh,0) & ":" & MMM & ":" & SSS
```

But what i am unsure of is how to implement this formula onto a data label.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to display the group name, and you can display and format the summarized value calculated by the chart, but you can't provide a custom formula. It just isn't possible using the chart library in CR XI.

My eventual workaround for this problem:

1. Modify the value formula to eliminate the aggregate function. (This is necessary because Crystal won't allow an aggregate function in a group name field -- see #2.)
2. For the group name, specify a formula with the text you want to display in the riser. Include both the label and the formatted value, separated by `Chr(13) & Chr(10)` to place them on separate lines.
3. Configure the riser to display the label, not the value.

To apply this to your problem you'd need to make these changes:

1. Eliminate the aggregate function. Of course I don't know if this will be possible using your setup. Perhaps if you're using a DBMS you could use a SQL command or a stored procedure to calculate the sum before the data reaches Crystal.
2. Print the label and value *together*, either on the riser or the X-axis.

If that's not good enough for your application, you might consider [CRChart](http://www.threedgraphics.com/tdg/products/tools/crchart/product_info.php), a commercial replacement which tries to address the sometimes-crippling limitations of Crystal's chart library. (I thought it was too pricey.) I think the [@APPEND_DATATEXT](http://www.threedgraphics.com/tdg/products/tools/crchart/html_docs/docs/macros/append_datatext.htm) macro would let you place a custom value on a riser, but you'd still need to move the summary to the server.