# Gantt chart in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

i have created a Gantt chart in Crystal Reports.  I have one problem.  I entered my date range with a beginning and ending date.  But when I try to show the value it shows me the number of days between the 2 dates.  I would like to display just the last date.  I am using Crystal Reports 2008.

Comment: How are you showing the value?

Comment: Just using the Chart Expert and selecting the check box to display the data on the chart.

Comment: Not sure if it's related to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639168/how-to-format-timevalue-to-hhmmss-in-datalabel/7652092#7652092